# C: How to list the count of the number of files and sub-directories in a directory

Tags: c, file, directory

Can someone tell me if I did this correctly to find the number of files and subdir in a directory? Also, how can I confirm this on in terminal?

```
main(int n, char *path[]){
//count the number of files and subdirectories
int fileCount = 0;
int dirCount = 0;
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *dir;

  int i;
  for(i = 1; i < n; i++){
        dp = opendir(path[i]);
        if(dp==NULL)
          continue;
        while((dir = readdir(dp)) != NULL){
          if(dir->d_type == DT_REG){
                fileCount++;
          }
          if(dir->d_type == DT_DIR)
                dirCount++;
        }
         printf("%s: file count is: %d and dir count is: %d\n",path[i], fileCount, dirCoun$
  }
// printf("file count is: %d and dir count is: %d", fileCount, dirCount);

closedir(dp);
}
```

Comment: You could verify it by actually going to one of the directories and listing all files there. Remember to list hidden files and directories as well, as your program counts them too (including the `.` and `..` directories).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but is there a command that will list the count of the files or sub dir of a directory? I think my code is wrong because when I actually display the files, my count seems to be short...

Comment: If you're on e.g. a Linux or OSX system, list using `ls -Fa`, that will show hidden files and also their categories (regular files, directories, pipes etc.). You could also do e.g. `find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -type d -o -type f | wc -l` to count all regular files and directories in `/path/to/dir`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [`nftw()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) for this? `opendir()`/`readdir()`/`closedir()` and `nftw()` are all POSIX.1-2001 functions, but `nftw()` is supposed to handle problem situations (like renames and deletes in the directory tree concerned) correctly, whereas your reinvent-the-wheel approach definitely does not. Besides, [`d_type` field is not supported by all filesystems](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html).

Comment: Also, if you have symbolic links or pipes or any other non-regular files or directories those might not be counted by your program, but listed when doing e.g. `ls -a`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal i didnt use ntfw() because I'm still pretty ignorant on stuff like this. I'll see if I can use that.

Answer (score 0):

Your program looks legit (except for typos).

To test it on a terminal after compilation simply type

`$./program-name DIR`

(e.g. `$./program-name .` for current directory).

It will count files and directories including hidden files and . and .. special directories. It will not recur inside sub-directories. *NIX command to count files in a directory (including hidden files) without recursion:

`$find DIR -type f -maxdepth 1 | wc -l`

Instead for counting directories

`$find DIR -type d -maxdepth 1 | wc -l`

(NOTE: you have to add 1 to the directory count since the .. directory will not be counted)